# Output PSQL query to STDOUT as CSV with bash script variables

Tags: bash, shell, csv, psql

I am trying to run a posgresql query from a bash script and return the result as a csv file to STDOUT. I am able to do that either with the --csv flag or COPY TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER without any issue. The problem comes from when I want to inject some variables using the -v flag. and that gives me the error of

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 5: WHERE b.regulator_id  = ANY(string_to_array(:ids,' ')::varch...
```

The command i'm running is

```
psql -U rs --csv -v ids="$(echo $deleted)" -c  "COPY (
SELECT     b.regulator_id,     b.name
FROM branch  b 
WHERE b.regulator_id  = ANY(string_to_array(:ids,' ')::varchar[])
GROUP BY b.regulator_id ) TO STDOUT" db
```

What would be the correct way to have the result of a psql query be returned as a csv and to STDOUT?

Comment: Why do you need $(echo $deleted)? Can you not just use "$deleted"

Comment: I had that before but I was just changing things in hope that one of them work.

Comment: I've just put it back to "$deleted" but its stil the same error

Comment: What's actually in the deleted variable?

Comment: Its a list of numbers for example 661060 557986 598185 524077 630420. String to be specific